Extend user session time for Kubernetes Nginx Ingress basic authentication
I applied basic HTTP authentication for Kubernetes Nginx Ingress, and the authentication works fine: user should enter login and password before opening some required URL. When the web-browser is, let say, restarted, the user must repeat login procedure again.
I would like to extend the session time from default (keeping while the web-browser is being opening) to some specific time (let say, 6 months). Is it possible with Nginx Ingress basic auth? Due to this issue it's not possible, but I would like somebody's confirmaiton, please.
I've tried to apply the sticky session, but it does not work as expected. However, as I see in developer tools, the web-browser receives required cookies and the expiration time (6 months) is set properly.
Also, I've met with such questions 1 , 2, but didn't find the solution too.
My Nginx Ingress config:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: doc-mycompany-com
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: doc-mycompany-com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: Authentication Required!
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 20M
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "15552000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "15552000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: doc-mycompany-com-session
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-14T12:26:28Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: doc-mycompany-com
  namespace: doc-mycompany-com
  resourceVersion: "280693994"
  uid: 39889b30-96d1-4983-9ed2-af69cdc1d272
spec:
  rules:
  - host: doc.mycompany.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: doc-mycompany-com
            port:
              name: http
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.235.74.63



Yes, it is not possible: to extend time of authentication while using Basic Authentication.
Proofs:

basic http authentication - duration of the session
nginx auth_basic time limitation
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/

To be able to manage time of session needs to implement different type of authentication, for example, External OAUTH Authentication.
